# Why does isFinite() return true for strings containing numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have multiple arrays containing different data; some numbers and strings.
As I'm trying to filter through the array list I was expecting the strings to return false, (unfortunately) the last test case array is returning true.

I can't find any information easily which could explain why this happens.

```js
function filter_list(l) {
  const filtered_l = l.filter(idx => isFinite(idx));
  console.log(filtered_l);
}

// test cases
filter_list([1,2,'a','b'])// == [1,2]
filter_list([1,'a','b',0,15])// == [1,0,15]

// this test case returns the strings too.
filter_list([1,2,'aasf','1','123',123])// == [1,2,"1","123",123] I expected [1,2,123]
```

Comment: @VLAZ I can see that it is returning true, hence the last test case is returning an array with the numbers which were a string inside the array.

I'm wondering why it isn't false, assuming it is a string just like 'aasf'. I can't see any clarification about that in the docs.

Comment: The input is implicitly converted to a number: `isFinite(value)` === `isFinite(Number(value))`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, isFinite() determine if a value is finite, and convert it to int or float if is necessary with parseInt or parseFloat, if u try parseInt with '123' the result will be 123 number but if u try with 'adf' for example the result will be NaN (Not a Number). You can use Number.isFinite('value') that is stronger and will cover your need.

Regards!

Comment: "*convert it to int or float if is necessary with parseInt or parseFloat*" 1. the JS number type is only floats, there are no integers (other than BigInt which is a separate thing). 2. The conversion is ***NOT*** done via `parseFloat` or `parseInt` as that will drastically change the result.

Comment: In which case would Number(val) convert a string to a number, though? It works but the docs say: "When used as a function, Number(value) converts a string or other value to the Number type. If the value can't be converted, it returns NaN."